# Maximizing TCP/IP speed with python driver

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, esp32, ethernet

I am working on fairly complex project that involves data transfer from ESP32 to PC via TCP/IP protocol. Both codes (I guess) are not worth to investigate on the spot, however, I will provide it down bellow. The main algorithm is as follows:

ESP32 constantly sampling a signal of interest via ADC12020 converter. When ESP32 receives an interrupt (meaning the signal has reached threshold level) it accumulates and forms 256 byte data packet and sends it to the PC via TCP/IP (ESP32 acting as client). This operation continues untill the ESP32 is powered down.

On the PC side I have wrote a python script that emulates a TCP server. Server is listening for incoming data. As soon as it receives a data packet from the client it assigns a timestamp to it and does minimal data processing steps (some bitwise operations) Then it forms some kind of a data unit (with correct formating, timestamp, number format etc.) and stores it in a 100 MB internal buffer. When the ESP32 ends its operation and disconnects, it indicates that there will be no more incoming data packets and the server should write all the accumulated results to a textfile.

All this is achieved successfully, except for the fact that I only get maximum of around 170 voltage pulses per second registered (judging on the timestamps and the result file data.) while the test conditions easily reach 10000 pulses per second. So 170 pulses/second * 256 bytes (one processed pulse digital volume) = 0.34 Mbit/s. This number looks crazy small considering ESP has standard 10/100 Mbit Ethernet interface (I am using ESP32 WROOVER-E ethernet kit) File write speed could have been a huge bottleneck, but now it is only writing file once in the end. Is it the timestamps assignment and bitwise operations that takes so long or the inherent slowness of python that prevents me from reasonable data transfer speeds? Any advices on how to improve it? Thank you in advance.

P.S My ESP32 is tested and really sending packets at actual voltage pulses rates (10-30k / second)

ESP32 client

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/gpio_struct.h"
#include "soc/gpio_reg.h"
#include "esp32/rom/ets_sys.h"
#include "soc/rtc.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "protocol_examples_common.h"
#include "esp_transport.h"
#include "esp_transport_tcp.h"
#include "esp_transport_socks_proxy.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TARGET_ADDR "169.254.157.27"
#define TARGET_PORT 5190

#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_PROXY
#define PROXY_ADDR CONFIG_EXAMPLE_PROXY_ADDR
#define PROXY_PORT CONFIG_EXAMPLE_PROXY_PORT
#endif

#define MAX_RETRY_COUNT 5
#define MAX_POLL_TIMEOUT_ERRORS 5
#define INTERRUPT_INPUT 15
#define GPIO_CLOCK 14
#define NUM_GPIO_PINS 12
#define NUM_CYCLES 64

#define GPIO_PIN_12 12
#define GPIO_PIN_13 13
#define GPIO_PIN_2 2
#define GPIO_PIN_4 4
#define GPIO_PIN_16 16
#define GPIO_PIN_17 17
#define GPIO_PIN_32 32
#define GPIO_PIN_33 33
#define GPIO_PIN_34 34
#define GPIO_PIN_35 35
#define GPIO_PIN_36 36
#define GPIO_PIN_39 39

uint64_t get_time_us() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (uint64_t)tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
}

static const char *TAG = "tcp_transport_client";
esp_transport_handle_t transport = NULL;
static bool is_connected = false;
static int unsuccessful_retries = 0;
static int consecutive_poll_timeout_errors = 0;
static bool received_from_server = false; // Flag to indicate if a message has been received from the server

static const gpio_num_t GPIO_PINS[NUM_GPIO_PINS] = {
    GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_4,
    GPIO_PIN_16, GPIO_PIN_17, GPIO_PIN_32, GPIO_PIN_33,
    GPIO_PIN_34, GPIO_PIN_35, GPIO_PIN_36, GPIO_PIN_39
};

bool trigger = false;
uint32_t data_array[NUM_CYCLES] = {0};

TaskHandle_t tcpTaskHandle;
SemaphoreHandle_t tcpMutex;
SemaphoreHandle_t dataReceivedSemaphore;
QueueHandle_t tcpDataQueue;
TimerHandle_t timerHandle;

int counter = 0; // Global variable to count interrupts
bool global_digit = false; // Global variable to store the least significant integer bit
int received_integer = 0;
bool timer_started = false;

// Function prototypes
void establish_connection();
void disconnect_if_connected();
void Impulse_Count();
void close_connection();
void send_data_over_tcp(uint32_t *data_array, size_t num_elements);
void send_data_task(void *pvParameters);
void receive_data_task(void *pvParameters);
static void IRAM_ATTR gpio_interrupt_handler(void *args);

void timerCallback(TimerHandle_t xTimer) {
    gpio_intr_disable(GPIO_NUM_15);
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); 
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Timer expired. Disconnecting from server...");
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  
    close_connection();
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Interrupt count: %d", counter);
}

void Impulse_Count(){
    vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); 
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Impulse target was reached. Disconnecting from server...");
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  
    close_connection();
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Interrupt count: %d", counter); 
}

float ntohf(float netfloat) {
    union {
        uint32_t n;
        float f;
    } tmp;

    tmp.n = htonl(*(uint32_t *)&netfloat);

    global_digit = (int)tmp.f & 1;

    int intPart = (int)tmp.f;
    float fracPart = tmp.f - intPart;

    if (intPart != 0) {
        intPart >>= 1; 
    } else {
        fracPart /= 2.0;
    }

    // Reconstruct the float
    tmp.f = intPart + fracPart;

    return tmp.f;
}

void establish_connection() {
    if (transport == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error: TCP transport not initialized");
        return;
    }

    const int connection_timings[MAX_RETRY_COUNT] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 0}; // 0 indicates no further attempts

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRY_COUNT; i++) {
        if (!is_connected) {
            vTaskDelay(connection_timings[i] * 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // Convert seconds to milliseconds
            int err = esp_transport_connect(transport, TARGET_ADDR, TARGET_PORT, 30000); // 30 second timeout
            if (err == 0) {
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connected successfully");
                is_connected = true; // Mark the connection as successful
                break; // Exit loop on successful connection
            } else {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Connection failed: errno %d", errno);
            }
        }
    }
}

void disconnect_if_connected() {
    if (is_connected) {
        int err = esp_transport_close(transport);
        if (err == 0) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Closed the connection successfully");
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error closing the connection: errno %d", errno);
        }
        is_connected = false;  // Mark the connection as unsuccessful
    }
}

void close_connection() {
    disconnect_if_connected();
}

void send_data_over_tcp(uint32_t *data_array, size_t num_elements) {
    if (transport == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error: TCP transport not initialized");
        return;
    }

    if (!is_connected || !received_from_server) { // Check if not connected or no message received from server
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error: Not connected to server or message not received from server");
        return;
    }

    size_t total_bytes_sent = 0;
    size_t remaining_elements = num_elements;
    uint8_t *data_ptr = (uint8_t *)data_array;

    int retry_count = 0;
    bool retry_exceeded = false;

    while (remaining_elements > 0 && !retry_exceeded) {
        int bytes_written = esp_transport_write(transport, (char *)data_ptr, sizeof(uint32_t) * remaining_elements, 0);

        if (bytes_written < 0) {
            int error_code = errno;
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error occurred during sending: esp_transport_write() returned %d, errno %d", bytes_written, error_code);

            if (error_code == ECONNRESET) {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Connection reset by peer. Attempting to reconnect...");
                is_connected = false;
                esp_transport_close(transport);
            } else {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unhandled error. Closing the transport.");
                esp_transport_close(transport);
            }

            consecutive_poll_timeout_errors++;  // Increment the error counter

            // Reset retry variables
            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  // Add a small delay before retrying
            continue;  // Retry without decrementing remaining_elements
        }

        if (bytes_written == 0) {
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Zero bytes written to TCP. Retrying...");
            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  // Add a small delay before retrying
            retry_count++;

            if (retry_count >= MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Maximum retry count exceeded. Disconnecting...");
                disconnect_if_connected();
                retry_exceeded = true;  // Set the flag to true
            }

            continue;  // Retry without decrementing remaining_elements
        }

        remaining_elements -= bytes_written / sizeof(uint32_t);
        data_ptr += bytes_written;
        total_bytes_sent += bytes_written;

        consecutive_poll_timeout_errors = 0;  // Reset the error counter on successful write

        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Sent %d bytes over TCP", bytes_written);  // Log only on successful send

         if(global_digit && (received_integer == counter)){
            //gpio_intr_disable(GPIO_NUM_15);
            Impulse_Count();   
        }
        counter++;
        //if(((received_integer > counter) && global_digit) || timer_started)
        //{
        //counter++;
        //}

    }
}

void receive_data_task(void *pvParameters) {
    char recv_buffer[256];
    int recv_len;
    //bool timer_started = false;

    while (1) {
        if (is_connected) {
            recv_len = esp_transport_read(transport, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer), 0);
            if (recv_len > 0) {
                float received_float;
                memcpy(&received_float, recv_buffer, sizeof(float));
                received_float = ntohf(received_float); // Convert float from network byte order to host byte order
                
                 // Adjust integer part
                //int intPart = (int)received_float;
                //intPart >>= 1; // Reduce by one bit
                //received_float = intPart + (received_float - intPart); // Reconstruct the float


                received_from_server = true;
                //counter = 0;
                
                if(!global_digit){
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received measurement time from server: %.3f s", received_float);

                uint32_t seconds = (uint32_t)received_float;  // Integer part represents seconds
                float fraction = received_float - seconds;    // Fractional part represents fractions of a second
                uint32_t microseconds = fraction * 1000000;  // Convert fraction to microseconds
                
                    if (!timer_started) {
                        if (timerHandle != NULL) {
                            xTimerDelete(timerHandle, 0);
                        }
                        timerHandle = xTimerCreate("Timer", pdMS_TO_TICKS(seconds * 1000 + microseconds / 1000), pdFALSE, NULL, timerCallback);
                        if (timerHandle != NULL) {
                            xTimerStart(timerHandle, 0);
                            timer_started = true; 
                        }
                    }
                }

                else {
                    received_integer = (int)received_float; // Directly cast to integer
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received impulse target from server: %d ", received_integer);
                }
                 xSemaphoreGive(dataReceivedSemaphore);
            }
        }
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  // Delay before retrying to receive data
    }
}


void send_data_task(void *pvParameters) {
    uint32_t received_data[NUM_CYCLES];
    int retry_delay = 1000;  // Initial retry delay in milliseconds

    while (1) {
        if (xSemaphoreTake(tcpMutex, portMAX_DELAY)) {
            if (xQueueReceive(tcpDataQueue, received_data, portMAX_DELAY)) {
                int retries = 0;
                int retry_delay = 0;  // Initial retry delay

                while (retries < 5) {
                    send_data_over_tcp(received_data, NUM_CYCLES);

                    if (is_connected) {
                        //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Sent %d bytes over TCP", sizeof(uint32_t) * NUM_CYCLES);
                        retry_delay = 0;  // Reset retry delay on successful send
                        break;  // Data sent successfully
                    } else {
                        // Connection failed, wait and retry with the specified delays
                        vTaskDelay(retry_delay / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                        retries++;

                        // Set the next retry delay according to the pattern
                        if (retries == 1) {
                            retry_delay = 1000;  // 1 second
                        } else if (retries == 2) {
                            retry_delay = 2000;  // 2 seconds
                        } else if (retries == 3) {
                            retry_delay = 3000;  // 3 seconds
                        } else if (retries == 4) {
                            retry_delay = 5000;  // 5 seconds
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (retries == 5) {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to send data after 5 retries. Performing a software reset...");

                    // Log the intentional reset
                    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Intentional reset triggered by software (esp_restart())");

                    esp_restart();  // Perform a software reset
                }
            } else {
                if (is_connected) {
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection lost. Attempting to reconnect...");
                    esp_transport_close(transport);
                    is_connected = false;
                    //last_reconnection_attempt_time = get_time_us();  // Record the time of the last reconnection attempt
                }
            }

            xSemaphoreGive(tcpMutex);
        }

    }
}

static void IRAM_ATTR gpio_interrupt_handler(void *args) {

        BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;

        uint32_t local_data_array[NUM_CYCLES];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CYCLES; ++i) {
            local_data_array[i] = data_array[i];
        }

        xQueueSendFromISR(tcpDataQueue, local_data_array, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
        //counter++; // Increment the counter each time an interrupt occurs

        if (xHigherPriorityTaskWoken == pdTRUE) {
            portYIELD_FROM_ISR();
        }
}

void app_main() {
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);  // Initial delay

    esp_log_level_set("transport", ESP_LOG_INFO);
    esp_log_level_set("transport_base", ESP_LOG_INFO);
    esp_log_level_set("transport_proxy", ESP_LOG_INFO);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(example_connect());
    transport = esp_transport_tcp_init();
    establish_connection();
    
#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_PROXY
    esp_transport_handle_t parent = transport;
    esp_transport_socks_proxy_config_t proxy_config = {.port = PROXY_PORT, .address = PROXY_ADDR, .version = SOCKS4};
    transport = esp_transport_socks_proxy_init(parent, &proxy_config);
#endif
    
    dataReceivedSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(receive_data_task, "TCP_Task", 8192, NULL, 3, &tcpTaskHandle, APP_CPU_NUM);  // Increased priority

    if (xSemaphoreTake(dataReceivedSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
        tcpDataQueue = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(data_array));

        xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(send_data_task, "TCP_Task", 8192, NULL, 4, &tcpTaskHandle, APP_CPU_NUM);  // Increased priority

        tcpMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();

        gpio_config_t io_conf_output = {
            .pin_bit_mask = (1ULL << GPIO_CLOCK),
            .mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT,
        };
        gpio_config(&io_conf_output);

        gpio_config_t io_conf;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GPIO_PINS; ++i) {
            io_conf = (gpio_config_t){
                .pin_bit_mask = (1ULL << GPIO_PINS[i]),
                .mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT,
                .intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE,
                .pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE,
                .pull_down_en = GPIO_PULLDOWN_ENABLE,
            };
            gpio_config(&io_conf);
        }

    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(INTERRUPT_INPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(INTERRUPT_INPUT, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_pulldown_en(INTERRUPT_INPUT);
    gpio_pullup_dis(INTERRUPT_INPUT);
    gpio_set_intr_type(INTERRUPT_INPUT, GPIO_INTR_NEGEDGE);

    gpio_install_isr_service(0);
    gpio_isr_handler_add(INTERRUPT_INPUT, gpio_interrupt_handler, (void *)INTERRUPT_INPUT);
        
        if(global_digit){
        counter = 0;
        }
    
    }

    uint8_t k = 0;
    while (1) {
        REG_WRITE(GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, (1 << GPIO_CLOCK));
        data_array[k] = REG_READ(GPIO_IN_REG);
        data_array[k + 1] = REG_READ(GPIO_IN1_REG);
        k = (k + 2) % NUM_CYCLES;
        REG_WRITE(GPIO_OUT_W1TC_REG, (1 << GPIO_CLOCK));
    }

    close_connection();

#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_PROXY
    esp_transport_destroy(parent);
#endif
}
```

Python server

```py
    import socket
    import struct
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import os
    import threading
    
    TARGET_IP = "169.254.157.27"
    TARGET_PORT = 5190
    BUFFER_SIZE = 256
    NUM_TO_PRINT = 32
    BUFFER_LIMIT = 100 * 1024 * 1024  # 100 MB
    
    accumulated_buffer = []
    timestamps = []
    cps_values = []
    active_connection = False
    total_logs_received = 0
    client_connection = None
    
    def process_data_chunk(data):
        result_array = (
            (((data[0] >> 12) & 1) << 0) |
            (((data[0] >> 13) & 1) << 1) |
            (((data[0] >> 2) & 1) << 2) |
            (((data[0] >> 4) & 1) << 3) |
            ((((data[0] >> 16) & 1) ^ 1) << 4) |
            (((data[0] >> 17) & 1) << 5) |
            (((data[1] >> 0) & 1) << 6) |
            (((data[1] >> 1) & 1) << 7) |
            (((data[1] >> 2) & 1) << 8) |
            (((data[1] >> 3) & 1) << 9) |
            (((data[1] >> 4) & 1) << 10) |
            (((data[1] >> 7) & 1) << 11)
        )
        return result_array
    
    def process_data(data, timestamp):
        result_array = np.array([process_data_chunk(struct.unpack("<II", data[i:i+8])) for i in range(0, len(data), 8)])
    
        max_index = np.argmax(result_array)
        lower_indices = np.arange(max_index, max_index + NUM_TO_PRINT // 2) % len(result_array)
        higher_indices = np.arange(max_index + NUM_TO_PRINT // 2, max_index + NUM_TO_PRINT) % len(result_array)
        lower_elements = result_array[lower_indices]
        higher_elements = result_array[higher_indices]
        rearranged_buffer = np.concatenate([higher_elements, lower_elements])
        max_index_rearranged = np.argmax(rearranged_buffer)
    
        rearranged_buffer = np.roll(rearranged_buffer, NUM_TO_PRINT // 2 - max_index_rearranged)
    
        timestamps.append(timestamp)
    
        return rearranged_buffer
    
    def print_decimal_chunks_to_file_and_terminal(data, file_path, timestamps, cps_values):
        global total_logs_received
        try:
            # Append timestamp to the filename
            timestamp_str = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
            filename = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + " " + timestamp_str + os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
    
            with open(filename, "a+") as file:
                for i in range(0, len(data), NUM_TO_PRINT):
                    timestamp = timestamps.pop(0)
                    cps = cps_values.pop(0)
                    formatted_timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.', time.localtime(timestamp)) + f"{timestamp:.6f}"[11:]
                    formatted_cps = f"{max(0, int(cps) - 1):d}" if cps is not None else "N/A"
                    file.write(f"{formatted_timestamp} - {formatted_cps} CPS - ")
                    line_data = data[i:i + NUM_TO_PRINT]
                    formatted_line = " ".join(f"{num:4d}" for num in line_data)
                    file.write(formatted_line)
                    file.write("\n")
                    total_logs_received += 1  # Increment the total_logs_received
    
        except Exception as write_error:
            print(f"Error writing to file: {write_error}")
    
    def count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps, current_timestamp):
        count = 0
        for ts in timestamps:
            if current_timestamp - ts < 1 and current_timestamp >= ts:
                count += 1
        return count
    
    def calculate_cps(timestamps):
        cps_values = []
        
        for i in range(len(timestamps)):
            cps = count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps[:i+1], timestamps[i])
            cps_values.append(cps)
        
        return cps_values
    
    def write_accumulated_data_to_file():
        global accumulated_buffer
        global timestamps
        global cps_values
    
        if accumulated_buffer and timestamps:
            try:
                cps_values = calculate_cps(timestamps)
                print_decimal_chunks_to_file_and_terminal(accumulated_buffer, "Rezultatai.txt", timestamps, cps_values)
                accumulated_buffer = []
                timestamps = []
                cps_values = []
                print("Baigta")
            except Exception as write_error:
                print(f"Error writing to file: {write_error}")
        else:
            print("No data to write.")
    
    def handle_client(connection, address):
        global active_connection
        global accumulated_buffer
        global timestamps
        global cps_values
    
        try:
            buffer = bytearray(BUFFER_SIZE)
            accumulated_data_size = 0
    
            while active_connection:
                try:
                    total_received = 0
                    while total_received < BUFFER_SIZE:
                        additional_data = connection.recv_into(buffer[total_received:])
                        if additional_data == 0:
                            print(f"Connection closed by the client ({address}) at {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')}")
                            active_connection = False
                            break
                        total_received += additional_data
    
                    if not active_connection:
                        break
    
                    timestamp = time.time()
                    data = process_data(buffer, timestamp)
    
                    #print(f"Received 256 bytes from {address}")
    
                    accumulated_buffer.extend(data)
                    accumulated_data_size += len(data)
    
                    if accumulated_data_size >= BUFFER_LIMIT:
                        print("Buffer size limit reached. Closing connection and writing data to file.")
                        write_accumulated_data_to_file()
                        active_connection = False
                        break
    
                    cps = count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps, timestamp)
                    cps_values.append(cps)
    
                except Exception as receive_error:
                    print(f"Error during data reception: {receive_error}")
                    break
    
            # Handle unexpected disconnection
            if active_connection:
                print("Unexpected disconnection detected. Closing connection and writing data to file.")
                write_accumulated_data_to_file()
                active_connection = False
    
        finally:
            connection.close()
            print("Connection closed.")
    
    def receive_data():
        global active_connection
        global client_connection
    
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
        try:
            server_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
            server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1048576)
    
            server_socket.bind((TARGET_IP, TARGET_PORT))
            server_socket.listen()
            print(f"Server listening on {TARGET_IP}:{TARGET_PORT}")
    
            while True:
                if not active_connection:
                    client_connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
                    print(f"Connected by {client_address}")
                    active_connection = True
    
                    # Request user input to determine the most significant bit
                    while True:
                        input_bit = input("Enter 0 if you want to specify the measurement time, 1 if you want to specify the number of impulses: ")
                        if input_bit in ['0', '1']:
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Invalid choice. Please enter 0 or 1.")
    
                    user_input = float(input("Enter the parameter: "))
                    
                    # Calculate final_float based on input bit
                    integer_part = int(user_input)
                    fractional_part = user_input - integer_part
                    
                    if input_bit == '0':
                        final_float = 2 * integer_part + fractional_part
                    else:
                        final_float = 2 * integer_part + 1 + fractional_part
    
                    print("Final float number:", final_float)
    
                    # Send user input to the client immediately after receiving it
                    user_input_packed = struct.pack("!f", final_float)
                    client_connection.sendall(user_input_packed)
                    print("Message sent")
    
                handle_client(client_connection, client_address)
    
        except Exception as bind_error:
            print(f"Error during socket bind: {bind_error}")
    
        finally:
            write_accumulated_data_to_file()
            server_socket.close()
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            receive_data()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Server shutting down gracefully.")
```

Comment: You should [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) your code to find the bottleneck.

Comment: The little ESP does not have the throughput for what you're trying to do. 10000 interrupts per second is already loading one core to the brim. The other core has probably reached its limit pushing 170 packets per second through the TCP/IP stack (it takes a fair amount of processing) Also TCP is not really friendly for fast, real-time transmissions - try UDP (you won't get 10000 packets per second but maybe 300-400?). You can get more details by enabling the [FreeRTOS run time stats](https://www.freertos.org/rtos-run-time-stats.html) and printing out the report.

Comment: But pay attention to my send_data_over_tcp function. I have a dedicated log message, if the packet was sent. On top of that I have a sent packets counter which is depicted in the end of the program. My terminal literally gets floded with logs and the counter number corresponds to the 10-30k pulses per second. Do you really think its an ESP problem?

Comment: You can optimize a bunch of things, sure. You can make a better thread architecture, faster protocol, etc. But the ESP will not push 10000 messages through its TCP/IP stack per second. By the way, writing log messages blocks the program until bytes are output via UART at 115200 baud (so there will be a delay of roughly 10us per character). Don't log anything if you're in a hurry.

Comment: Neither will WiFi permit 10000 individual transmissions per second. One more suggestion, you can batch the messages to get significantly better throughput. Don't send 1 message per packet. Collect an MTU sized buffer (around 1500) of messages and send those together.

Comment: Everything @Tarmo said is correct. Also, the fact that you can connect a 10/100Mbps ethernet interface is irrelevant. Those are the speeds at which the ethernet interface signals, they have nothing to do with the possible speed at which the ESP32 can transmit data other than being an absolute upper limit.

Comment: Right, Ethernet not Wifi. 100FX Ethernet might theoretically permit 10000 frames per second with a 256B TCP payload, but the ESP32's CPU is orders of magnitude slower creating them.